# angularjs form validation - 2 fields either could change

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have 2 text fields in my form. 1 is for date of birth. The other is for when someone wishes to retire.

The date of birth can be any time in the last 100 years.

The retirement age must be between the date of birth and today.

This means that should the date of birth change the retirement age field must change it's min and max validation properties.

This is currently working fine, but there is a case where it doesn't work. It can be reproduced by:

Enter date of birth.
angular changes the min max of retirement age and validates the age input correctly.
Modify the date of birth.
I need the retirement age field to revalidate because although the min/max have changed, angular still thinks it's valid.

Hope that makes sense.

```
<input type="text" id="id_dob" class="form-control" name="dateOfBirth" data-ng-model="user.dateOfBirth" date-of-birth placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
<input type="text" id="id_intendRetireInput" class="form-control" name="retirementAge" data-ng-model="user.retirementAge" integer required app-min="{{retirementmin}}" app-max="{{retirementmax}}" />
```

app.js

```
calculonApp.directive('dateOfBirth', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        if (moment(viewValue, "DD/MM/YYYY") < scope.min || moment(viewValue, "DD/MM/YYYY") > scope.max) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('dateOfBirth', false);
          return undefined;
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('dateOfBirth', true);
          scope.retirementmin = moment().diff(moment(viewValue, "DD/MM/YYYY"), 'y');
          return viewValue;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});

 calculonApp.directive('appMin', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      return ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
        var valid = value == null || Number(value) >= Number(attrs.appMin);

        ctrl.$setValidity('min', valid);

        return valid ? value : undefined;
      });
    }
  };
});

calculonApp.directive('appMax', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      return ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
        var valid = value == null || Number(value) <= Number(attrs.appMax);

        ctrl.$setValidity('max', valid);

        return valid ? value : undefined;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: why don't you reset the retirement age when birth date changes?

Comment: The simplest solutions are usually best. Thank you :)